# Can I call specific methods from file.php using JavaScripts fetch() function?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I was rather new to OOP and JavaScript at the time of asking this question and I have gained some more experience with both since I asked this question.

Originally I had asked how to call a specific method in a php file with multiple methods, I did not know that it would be easier and better to make a REST api of sorts.

To implement these changes I would change this function:
display.php

```
# Display's All Series
protected function SeriesDisplay()
{
  try {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM series';
    $stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $rows;
  } catch (TypeError $error) {
    return "Series Display Error: " . $error->getMessage();
  }
}
```

To an endpoint, the endpoint includes and initializes the class with all the functions in it and then calls the `SeriesDisplay()` function and echos the results as json for the fetch to grab and resolve.

New display.php:

```
// Includes the database to create a connection on class initialization.
include_once __DIR__ . '/../../config/database.php';

// Includes the series class containing all of the functions.
include_once __DIR__ . '/../../class/series.php';

// Initialize and connect database
$db = new Database();
$conn = $db->connect();

// Initialize series class with database connection
$items = new Series($conn);

// Call the function to get all the series from that database
$stmt = $items->SeriesDisplay();

// Assigns the database fetch results to an associative array and echos the JSON encoded array. If the fetchAll fails it echoes an array with an "error" saying not_found which can be used for error handling later on.
if ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo json_encode($row);
} else {
    http_response_code(204);
    echo json_encode(["series" => "not_found"]);
}
```

The `SeriesDisplay()` function and the class its in would have been modified to look like this now:

```
class Series
{
    // DB Connection variable
    private $conn;

    // Table To Access
    private $table = "series";

    // Columns in the Database
    public $UID;
    public $Title;
    public $Description;
    public $Chapters;
    public $Folder;
    public $Image;
    public $ExistingImage;
    public $Created;

    // Initiates database connection with connection provided in class initialization and creates a folder to store the series in if it doesn't exist.
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->conn = $db;
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . "/../series")) {
            mkdir(__DIR__ . "/../series");
        }
    }

    // Simple function without error handling, just attempts to grab everything from the database table and sends the array to the endpoint.
    public function SeriesDisplay()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $this->table";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

Finally my fetch would look like this:

```
fetch("/../api/series/display.php")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    // data would be used like so
    for (let i = 0; i < data.body.length; i++) {
        // data[i].UID | data.body[i].Title etc
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup an ajax script to send the fetch request to. For example, you can have `ajax.php` on your server and make a `fetch` request to that via the url... `https://example.com/ajax.php`

Then you would send the relevant data to that from the fetch request. In your example, you would use the `GET` method. If you wanted to use a different function depending on the data you would simply access the data from the fetch request by looking in the `$_GET` array.

Example

ajax.php

```php
function foo(){
   echo 'foo';
}

function bar(){
   echo 'bar';
}

if($_GET['action'] == 'foo'){
    foo();
} elseif($_GET['action'] == 'bar') {
    bar();
}

exit();
```

index.js

```js
fetch('https://example.com/ajax.php', {
    method: 'GET',
    body: {
        action:'bar'
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Clearly this is a very simple example and lacks any form of security or sanitization but this is essentially how ajax works.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the example that clears some things up and gives me some ideas to try. Ill use ajax if I have to.

Comment: Your answer really helped push me to learning what I have now, using your explanation and some googling I was eventually able to figure out I should make a sort of rest API.

Answer (score 2):

`fetch` is a browser built-in API for making HTTP requests from JS. Ajax is a buzzword meaning “make HTTP requests from JS in the browser”. jQuery is a library which includes some functions to help make HTTP requests.

Interactions between JS in a browser and PHP on a server can only take place by sending HTTP requests and getting responses (there are also Web Sockets but that is another story).

HTTP requests are made to URLs.

**You can’t make an HTTP request to a PHP function.**

You can write a PHP file which does nothing except call a particular function and then put that file on your web server so it has a URL you can call.

Some PHP frameworks will provide a routing mechanism that expects you to assign a function to any given route.

Comment: I see, then that would mean not even Jquery/Ajax could help me. Maybe I am going about things the wrong way then. Time to research some more then. Thank you though!